# C# Word 2010 Interop Automatically number headings like standard button does

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop, office-interop, heading

My problem: I generate a `Word` `.doc` from another tool. Well this tool has problems with generate appropriate heading numbers. (Heading 1 to Heading x is assigned right, but the numbers are somehow wrong).

So what I did was not let the headings get numbered (the style is set correctly).

When I open the .doc (I need to update the TOC and do other stuff) I'd like to let the headings get numbered automatically. (Just like at Word 2010 when you press the button "List with many level" and select the option where the headings get numbered just as I want them to (the standard word functionality)).

Has anyone done something like this? I mean, the functionality is within `Word`, so I don't believe that it's impossible to tell word by interop to do this with the opened document.

I can't find an option or method which will allow me to do so.

Comment: Start by recording the necessary steps in a Word macro to get the basic syntax, then you can "translate" the VBA to C#. We can't possibly give you the exact code since what you describe is not a single option in the Word object model. And the numbering permutations are innumerable.

Comment: Holy Moly! This is plenty of code.
But as I see now, the other threads were right, when they did those many steps to accomplish this.
Thank you very much for your suggestion - helped me out a lot!

Best Regards,
Eric

Comment: You're welcome. Note that you probably wouldn't need ALL the code, the trick is knowing what you can/should leave out :-) For example, if you only use Heading styles 1 through 3 or 4 you wouldn't need the definitions for the other 6 or 5 numbering levels.